# Tabs on Tab Bar Controller iOS doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a segue from the tabs on the Tab Bar Controller. But I cannot attach them to anything! What am I doing wrong?

If I click on the tab bars (I have 2), none of them updated the current view displayed.

Also, how can I customize their widths? I want each to take up 50% of the bar; unlike here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how you attaching segue from tab bar ?

Comment: You need to go for custom tabbar for its width and regarding your issue please post your storyboard image so we can get idea whats going wrong.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/c8Sxa

Comment: updated description with screen shot

Comment: @konyv12, actually do not connect segue just connect `viewController` by using cltr drag mouse pointer to vc.

Comment: @vaibhav please give more details. I don't know what u mean

Comment: @konyv12, please check my ans.